# what affects page redraw performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My web page loads up quickly but takes time on the frontend to render.

I have a lot of JS CSS and images on the page.

I have gone to Google PageSpeed insights and in terms of network connections etc. the page is good.

Yes it does mention to minify static resources (JS/CSS/HTML) on the server. But will that improve page redraw.

I need faster rendering times. How do I make this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the initial rendering when the page first loads, or subsequent redraws as the user (and/or your JS) interact with the page? If you minify those resources they will download faster, thereby reducing the elapsed time between when the page is first requested and when rendering finishes.

Comment: Normally browsers handle rendering pretty well and fast, unless you have literally thousands and thousands of elements.

Comment: i've found that many designers don't realize how much some CSS effects penalize page rendering and scrolling: especially box-shadow, rgba colors, opacity, and text-shadow.

Comment: I've found that large background images covering the entire document with ```position``` set to ```fixed``` really takes its toll.

Comment: _redraw_ time should not hinge much on minified resources, as those should be cached anyway. in fact, having all your stuff in one file can be slower than pipelining many smaller files, and allows a progressive rendering, thus decreasing the perceived load time. there is a new "above the fold" posse forming, but i think that's going a bit too far...

Answer (score 2):

[csstriggers](http://csstriggers.com/) is a handy reference by Paul Lewis list down all the css/style rules that affects **paint, layout & composite**.

Answer (score 1):

Google Developers recommendations are:

- Use efficient CSS selectors
- Avoid CSS expressions
- Put CSS in the document head
- Specify image dimensions
- Specify a character set

Details in [Optimize browser rendering](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering)

Chrome dev tools can help with profiling and finding bottle necks here is a [guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) and [another one](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2014/04/09/improve-rendering-performance-with-chrome-dev-tools/).

If you do have time check Crash course on web performance (Fluent 2013) it's so interesting and worth every second, if you want just the rendering part see:

- [Delivering 60 FPS in the browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpNXWxMyzHQ)
- [Critical rendering path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkOBnYxqj3k)